# I cannot convert from MYSQL_ROW to a System::String type without a runtime error

Tags: c++, mysql

Ok, so im trying to convert a MYSQL_ROW to an object in order to format it and put it in a label, but it sends me an run-time error code. 
This is the code:

```
sprintf(query, "SELECT Dinero FROM `cuentas` WHERE Username='%s'", result);
                mysql_query(conn, query);
                resultado = mysql_store_result(conn);
                if(resultado)
                {
                    unsigned int num_fields;
                    unsigned int i;
                    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(resultado);
                    columnas = mysql_fetch_row(resultado);
                    while(columnas)
                    {
                        for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
                        {
                            label4->Text = String::Format(L"Dinero: {0}\n",Convert::ToString(atoi(columnas[i])));
                        }
                    }
                }
                mysql_free_result(resultado);
```

It compiles fine but when i execute-it i get a run-time error.

Comment: Which error do you get? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following two lines:

```
columnas = mysql_fetch_row(resultado);
while(columnas)
```

Whith this single line:

```
while(columnas = mysql_fetch_row(result ado))
```

So that, your full code becomes:

```
sprintf(query, "SELECT Dinero FROM `cuentas` WHERE Username='%s'", result);
            mysql_query(conn, query);
            resultado = mysql_store_result(conn);
            if(resultado)
            {
                unsigned int num_fields;
                unsigned int i;
                num_fields = mysql_num_fields(resultado);
                while(columnas = mysql_fetch_row(resultado))
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
                    {
                        label4->Text = String::Format(L"Dinero: {0}\n",Convert::ToString(atoi(columnas[i])));
                    }
                }
            }
            mysql_free_result(resultado);
```